# How to define child static class which extends parent abstract?

Tags: java, oop

I need a parent public abstract class which will have  multiple child public static classes. I need only one instance of a Weapon class, a few static classes Bow, Sword< etc which extend the parent and can exist also only in one instance (at least I need to be able to get their static fiels). How to do it properly?

```
public abstract  class Weapon {
    ...
}
public static class Bow extends  Weapon { 
      static String type = "Bow ";
      static  int damage = 10;
}

public static class Sword extends  Weapon { 
      static String type = "Sword";
      static int damage = 10;
}
```

Getting error:

```
Illegal modifier for the class Sword; only public, abstract & final are permitted
```

---

I removed static and it worked:

```
public final class   Sword extends  Weapon { 
      static String type = "Sword";
      static int hitPointsTaken = 10;
}
```

---

I can compile this `System.out.println(   Sword.type  );` but not this `System.out.println(   Weapon.Sword.type  );` . Does it mean that I cannot access child through parent abstract?

Comment: And where's the code for the `Sword` class?

Comment: By trying to do Weapons.Sword.type, it seems that you think that deriving a class via "extends" and nesting a class are the same thing.  They are not.  The first creates an "is a" relationship; Sword is a Weapon.  The second creates a "has a" relationship; Weapon has a Sword.  The dot operator allows you to access fields, methods, etc. an object has, not other classes derived from the same class as a given object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you absolutely have to implement this model, you're looking at nesting:

```
public abstract  class Weapon {

    public static class Bow extends  Weapon { 
          static String type = "Bow ";
          static  int hitPointsTaken = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, only nested classes can be static, and it doesn't mean what you think it means, then, either.  What you really want to do if something should only have one instance is use a Singleton pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Example

Comment: You should never force yourself to have a single instance of an object. It's fine to have a single instance, passing it around, but don't force it. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40373/so-singletons-are-bad-then-what

Comment: I hate singletons myself, but given the subject matter, I didn't want to descend into a architecture discussion with someone who needs to learn a bit more about basic OOP before the reasons why singletons are bad will even make sense.

Comment: That doesn't mean you should be corrupting his mind with evil! Shoo! Cthulhu! Shoo!!!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot declare a public static class out of the parent class scope. Try doing like this

```
public abstract class Weapon {
    public abstract void usage();

    public static class Sword extends Test{

        @Override
        public void usage() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
}
```

One instance you can achieve it by making the constructor of Weapon class as private and have a getInstance() method to create a single instance of the class. This is known as Singleton pattern, but please make it singleton if your design really needs else don't go for that because it will make your code tough to write tests and also for future changes.

Answer (score 1):

If an **Object** can only exist in one instance (i.e. I only have one sword in my werehouse), it doesn't mean it should be a **static Class**. It should still be an object. What if by some cosmic event your best friend the blacksmith would give you a free `Sword` tommorow? What would you do then?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access a single instance of the Bow class statically, you can make the Bow class have a non-public constructor and initialize a public static instance of it.  (`public static Bow THE_BOW = new Bow(...);`)  This should take care of your static and inheritance desires.  If this doesn't make sense let me know and I'll provide a code example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are miss understanding the meaning of the static keyword.  I am new to Java so I had to go look it up myself.  (that is one of the reasons I surf this site so much... I learn a lot too).  I found [this: Secrets of Static in Java with Example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2011/11/static-keyword-method-variable-java.html) site in my bookmarks that explains the static keyword in detail.  Good luck with your project.

Comment: My answer assumes you don't intentionally want only a single instance of your class (which is the usual use of the static keyword).

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this an `enum` pattern?

```
public enum Weapon {
  Bow(10),
  Sword(10);

  private int damage;

  Weapon (int damage) {
    this.damage = damage;
  }

  public int getDamage () {
    return damage;
  }
}
```

**Added** ... or more dramatically

```
public enum Weapon {
  Bow(10) {
    @Override
    public void strike(Warrior warrior) {
      // Inflict the normal damage.
      super.strike(warrior);
      // Sometimes also sicken.
      if ( Math.random() > .95 ) {
        warrior.sicken(Illness.ArrowInTheKnee);
      }
    }
  },
  Sword(10) {
    @Override
    public void strike(Warrior warrior) {
      // Inflict the normal damage.
      super.strike(warrior);
      // Sometimes also sicken.
      if ( Math.random() > .75 ) {
        warrior.sicken(Illness.StabInTheBack);
      }
    }
  };

  // Normal damage inflicted.
  private int damage;

  Weapon(int damage) {
    this.damage = damage;
  }

  public int getDamage() {
    return damage;
  }

  public void strike(Warrior warrior) {
    warrior.inflict(damage);
  }

  // Placeholder
  public interface Warrior {
    public void inflict(int damage);
    public void terrorise(int fear);
    public void sicken (Illness illness);
  }

  enum Illness {
    StabInTheBack,
    ArrowInTheKnee;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it is use Singleton pattern for your 'class Weapon'.

Make your constructor private and use getInstance() method to retrieve your Weapon instance. After this create your subclasses for Bow and Sword.

Answer (score 0):

you can use subclass as static class like below

```
public class Bow extends  Weapon {

  private static Bow object = null;

  public Bow(){
    object = this;
  }

  public static getObjectAsStatic(){
    return object;
  }

}
```

Now you can call any class member with "Bow.getObjectAsStatic()" like Bow.getObjectAsStatic().classMembers